# How to refresh the Datagridview when the Database has been restored from .bak without restarting the app using Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

> **Important Edit**
>
> > *I solved the problem. It was not a problem actually. What was happening is when I debug the program a new .mdf file creates in the debug folder from which my Datagridview and other objects in the application gets information. But the restore query I used was restoring the database on my solution folder (the main .mdf file) so each time I finish my operation the solution file gets restored and showed on the next time I debug as it re create the .mdf file on the debug folder from the solution folder. And hence could view then on the next debug.*

I have created a built in Backup/ Restore application is which I am able to Backup & Restore successfully but when restored successfully I have to close the app and restart it again to view the changes but I don't want to close the app instead I want it to appear the changes immediately after successfully restored, so is it possible? If yes then how?

Screenshot of the form:
[image: Screenshot of the form]

Current Code:

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Test


    Sub Backup()
        With SaveFileDialog1
            .FileName = ""
            .Filter = "Backup File|*.bak"
            SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            If .FileName = "" Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Dim BUDate As New TextBox
                BUDate.Text = "Backup database BISDB To Disk='" + SaveFileDialog1.FileName + "'"
                Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=BISDB;Integrated Security=True")
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

                Try
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.CommandText = BUDate.Text
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Backup successfull!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Backup")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try
            End If
        End With


    End Sub

    Private Sub Test_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Backup()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRestore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRestore.Click
        With OpenFileDialog1
            .FileName = ""
            .Filter = "Backup File|*.bak"
            OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            If .FileName = "" Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                Dim BUDate As New TextBox
                BUDate.Text = "RESTORE DATABASE BISDB FROM Disk='" + FileName + "'"
                Dim con2 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")
                Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(BUDate.Text, con2)

                Try
                    con2.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Restore Successfull!")
                    Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students) '//Edited According to Vignesh Kumar's Answer
                    Me.StudentsBindingSource.ResetBindings(False) '//Edited According to GuidoG's Answer
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Finally
                    con2.Close()
                    con2.Dispose()

                End Try
            End If
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        'Me.BIS.Reset()
        'Me.StudentsBindingSource.Dispose()
        'Me.StudentsBindingSource.ResetAllowNew()
        Me.StudentsBindingSource.ResetBindings(True)
        Me.StudentsBindingSource.SuspendBinding()
        Me.StudentsBindingSource.ResumeBinding()

        Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students)
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

### Names of items:

**Refresh Button - btnClose**

**Backup Button - btnCalculate**

**Restore Button - btnRestore**

**Datagridview - DataGridView1**

**Form - Test**

I Start the application by clicking on Start Button :
[image]

I use bindingsource to fill the DataGridView and don't use any code to fill the DataGridView but `Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students)`
While loading the form.

### This is what I got till now:

```
Dim command = New SqlCommand("", con2)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = adapter
        adapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students)
```

Comment: I dont know because I dont know how you show your data now ? Do you have some code to connect to the database and how do you fill your datagrid ? Do you use a bindingsource or a datatable or something else ? How are we supposed to help you if you give us no information ?

Comment: Okay, check my edit... And Sorry... And please give answer by clicking on **Post Your Answer** instead of writing comment so if your answer helps me I can mark it as Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you have to refill your datagrid after a succesfull restore.
Look for the comment
// Refill the datagrid after succesfull restore
in my answer

```
Private Sub
    With OpenFileDialog1
        .FileName = ""
        .Filter = "Backup File|*.bak"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If .FileName = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            Dim BUDate As New TextBox
            BUDate.Text = "RESTORE DATABASE BISDB FROM Disk='" + FileName + "'"
            Dim con2 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")
            Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(BUDate.Text, con2)

            Try
                con2.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                // Refill the datagrid after succesfull restore
                Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students)

                MsgBox("Restore Successfull!")

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Finally
                con2.Close()
                con2.Dispose()

            End Try
        End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

EDIT: things to try out
put a button on the form anywhere and try this code in it :

```
yourDataGridView.BindingSource = null
Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students)       
yourDataGridView.BindingSource = Me.StudentsBindingSource
Me.StudentsBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
```

EDIT : Fill command with same connection
(sorry this is in c# I dont known visual basic)

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("your query", con2);
command.CommandType = Command.Text;
SqlAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students);
```

EDIT : user different database for the query :

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("use BISDB " + your query, con2);
```

Comment: I think this code is same as my edited code " **Edited According to _Vignesh Kumar_'s Answer:** , If so then sorry this doesn't work...

Comment: Should I have to publish the app first to refill my datagridview automatically?

Comment: If you really fill the datagridview with the command "Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students)" than this should have worked. Are you sure that the data in the table has changed after the restore ? Can you check this first please ?

Comment: Yeah, The data in table has changed because when I close the app completely and then click on the **_Start_ button** then I can see the changes... 



**NOTE: I tried this by click on Start button on Visual Studio 2015 while editing the application** So is this happening because I have to clean the build every time?

Comment: maybe there is some other code that we do not see here that does this. From the info I see here this should have worked. If this form is not to large maybe you can post all code ? Or at least anything that touches the datagridview and the bindingsource ?

Comment: You can also try this after the Fill method : bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

Comment: OK, check my edit, I edited according to your comment. And did you mean I should add `Me.StudentsBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)` below `Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students)` , | If so than I tried but don't work :(

Comment: when you start the application there will be some records in the datagrid right ? Now before you call "btnRestore_Click" use a tool like "sql server managment studio" to check the data that is in the table at this point.  Now when you call "btnRestore_Click" you must check in your database agein it the data has changed at this time. It is important that you check this immediate after you have called "btnRestore_Click" and that you leave the application open while you check this. This is the only way to be sure that the data really has changed at this time.

Comment: From what I read in your last comment I have a strong feeling that the data has not changed yet at this point.

Comment: Ok, checked! and the data really has changed

Comment: Than it should also change in your datagrid with the current code. Try putting the .Fill and the .ResetBindings in onClick of a test button and see what it does. If still nothing than try to set the bindingsource of the datagridview to null and than assign it back again. If still nothing than use a profiler tool to check what command is actually send to the database.

Comment: I'm uploading a video to show you what actually happens... I will post it as soon as possible... And I'm checking your .Fill & .RB options

Comment: which one should I put first? .Fill or .RB?

Comment: Like this, `Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students) Me.StudentsBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)`  ?

Comment: Than you have to use a profiler to see what command is actually been send to the database.

Comment: So here is the [Sample Video](https://youtu.be/02DghmspmU8)



Please let me know if you watched and your opinion...

Comment: I looked at your video and when I look at your source I do not see anything wrong so it should have worked in my opinion. Have you tried a test button already with the .fill and the RB code ? I should start from there and than you can test code there until you find something that works. Only thin I can think of so soon is to set the bindingsource of the datagrid to null before you call the fill and then set it back before you call the RB

Comment: Can you check with a profiler what command is send to the database when you start the application, and what command is send when you press restore ? They should be exact the same.

Comment: Ok then can you please edit my question and let me know wht should I do?

Comment: Ok I'll check as soon as possible

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you what you can still try

Comment: I noticed that you create a new connection (con2) for the restore command. Might it be possible that the .Fill is using another connection ?? That might explain what is going on here the .Fill will succeed but since it is using another connection it might not yet see the changes.

Comment: Then what should I do? What should I do to see the changes?

Comment: Use the same connection object for the restore and backup commands as you are using for your .Fill command

Comment: Can you give me complete clean step by step way that I should do assuming I had just created the Form Test and designed the form with items listed above and with zero code... And can I backup `.mdf file ` without SSMS but just my app?

Comment: how does your fill command knows what database to use then ? It sounds to me like the fill is using another database than the restore. Can you tell me how the fill command connects to the datatase ?

Comment: I have inserted StudentsBindingSource, StudentsTableAdatapter and DataSet as BIS -----   I used this through Designer and no code used here...

Comment: and how in the designer did you point to the correct database ? (I never use the designer for this I created my own database controls)

Comment: I Pointed to the database by following this methods :
[1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NgaA5.png)
[2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BayHu.png)
[3](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U8lKW.png)

Comment: Is there any alternative way to Backup mdf file?

Comment: The problem is not with your backup/restore commands. You should create your own connection to use for the fill command so you have more control over it.

Comment: I have edited my answer on how you can use con2 for the fill command also, try this lets see if it works

Comment: Since I am new in this please can you tell what should I replace with query?

Comment: And check my edits: **This is what I got till now:**

Comment: I dont know your table so I cannot give you exact query, it should be something like this: SELECT field1, field2 FROM yourtable

Comment: you must set the datagridview1.datasource to Me.BIS.Students not to adapter and do this after the fill

Comment: Hey my SqlConnection **con2** to Restore has **Initial Catalog=master** Because I can't restore my database **BISDB** while the connection open for that Database... | Code: `Dim con2 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")` So I can't use same connection

Comment: yes you can you have to put this command first in the fill query : use BISDB and in the command for the backup/restore you put as first command use master

Comment: Okay I changed **con2 Query** from `Dim con2 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")` to `Dim con2 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True")`  **Change = Removed Initial Catalog=master** ||| -- Info: The restore process still work, [Without the initial catalog query] But to fill the Datagridview I have to mention Initial Catalog=BISDB otherwise it won't work

Comment: Ok, got it now I can use same connection for 2 query, but The change is When the table has no Row then I restore "Filled.bak" and it loads the row but when it has Rows and I restore from "Blank.bak" then it doesn't load i.e, it still shows that there are rows but actually there is no rows and it appears correctly if I restart the app

Comment: when restarting the app you have to use the same connection again for the fill command have you checked that ? All fill commands and all restore/backup commands have to use the same connection

Comment: Hey do you have Facebook account? If yes then please can you give it I want to add you as Friend... I need your help

Comment: And yeah I have checked that I use the same connection for Backup/Restore and Fill... But the result is same as my comment just before your last comment... And can I have same connection for the whole project? I mean can I use the same connection in all form without assigning it individually in each form?

Comment: normally you dont need to use the same connection as long as the connectionstrings are exact the same and you use the same database. I wanted you to use the exact same connection to be sure all commands are executed on the same database. If it still does not works than then there has to be something wrong with your code that I cannot detect

Comment: Ok lets make it clear to you, I use only one database to run the whole project, so if I need same connection for .Fill and Backup/ Restore on this so also I should need same connection for all other forms right?

Comment: but you are using the same connection and still you dont see the changes this cannot be unless there is something else wrong that I cannot see

Comment: Ok I did some experiment in this and found that It actually shows changes if the "RestoreFileName.bak" has number of rows more than or equal to the number of rows of "Current Database" but does not show changes if the "RestoreFileName.bak" has number of rows less than the number of rows of "Current Database". **I will post a video of the process as soon as possible**

Comment: this sounds like the visual basic bug that is in it from version 1 is still in it. You need to fill your datagridview with a complete other table and than fill it back with the correct table otherwise visual basic refuses to update its datagridview. Its one of the reasons why visual basic is hated so much.

Comment: Tried that too! First I set the datasource to different table then to Students but now still the results are same..

Comment: This should already long be working there is something else wrong. Post your code in the shown of the form and the code for there restore and fill again please. Also use a profiler to compare the commands that are send to the database they should be exact the same

Answer (score 1):

You can call the bindingsource to fill the `DataGridView` While restoring the database.

```
Me.StudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BIS.Students)
```

Try like below:

```
  Private Sub
        With OpenFileDialog1
            .FileName = ""
            .Filter = "Backup File|*.bak"
            OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            If .FileName = "" Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                Dim BUDate As New TextBox
                BUDate.Text = "RESTORE DATABASE BISDB FROM Disk='" + FileName + "'"
                Dim con2 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")
                Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(BUDate.Text, con2)

                Try
                    con2.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Restore Successfull!")
                    ' DataGrdiview Binding Code
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Finally
                    con2.Close()
                    con2.Dispose()

                End Try
            End If
        End With
   End Sub
```

Comment: Tried but doesn't work...
**NOTE: I tried this by click on _Start_ button on Visual Studio 2015 while editing the application**



   So is this happening because I have to clean the build every time?